# Is there a way to get truly unanswered questions of a certain tag?

Tags: support, search, unanswered-questions

If I go to "unanswered" and select a tag, I see questions with unconfirmed answers. Is there any way to see all questions with 0 answers of a certain tag(confirmed or not)? If not, can this be added?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `answers` keyword:

```
[c++] answers:0
```

Brings up [all questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]+answers%3A0) tagged `c++` with zero (0) answers. There are [other goodies](https://stackoverflow.com/search) too.

You can then click on the Newest or Activity tabs to sort by either posting time of question or last modification to the entire question-answer set.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I search "[objective-c] answers: 0", the query returns questions which have answers. Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=, answers specifies "questions that have a minimum number of answers". I am interested in the maximum answers associated with a question.

Comment: Get rid of the space: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[objective-c]+answers%3A0

Comment: Don't forget to exclude closed questions!