# How to get a list of all questions with a particular tag and '0 answers', in descending posting order

Tags: support, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get truly unanswered questions of a certain tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34364/is-there-a-way-to-get-truly-unanswered-questions-of-a-certain-tag)

I would like to list all recent questions that have had no responses at all.