# How can I view a list of all questions with no answers at all, most recent ask date/time at top, and filterd by specific tags?

Tags: feature-request, support, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get truly unanswered questions of a certain tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34364/is-there-a-way-to-get-truly-unanswered-questions-of-a-certain-tag)

There are similar questions to this but I didn't see one with this exact scenario.  Specifically with getting the most recent questions with zero answers listed first.

On a SE site that focuses on technology (frequent change) I really don't want the list of questions with zero answers to start with the ones that were asked 2+ years ago if I only have 10 minutes to browse/answer.

Ideally the UI would let me easily click, "show me a list of all questions with no answers at all, sorted with most recent at top, and only tagged with this tag and that tag".

If the UI won’t let me do it without typing, can you tell me the custom syntax I should use to achieve this and where to type it in?

If it is not possible to do this yet, here are my initial thoughts as to the desired feature:

I realize that being able to filter like this in the early days of SO/SE may have led to "older" (a few days) questions not getting answered properly but IMO as you get 10K to 1M+ unanswered questions on a SE site, many people will just move on and not bother to sift (next next next) to find the 1 question they actually know the answer to *that may still be relevant to answer*.

Maybe this UI behavior should be enabled depending on how mature/large/active the community for the site is and/or how many questions remain unanswered?  Maybe those are ways to know, "ok, this site has at least n experts that can spend a lot of time here every day as well as another n that can only spend a few minutes here and there.  Because of that, let's assume that on this SE site the "unanswered" (no up votes/checks) questions have a shot at getting enough eyeballs at some point and give this major site the ability to sort questions this way without typing (UI clicks/touch)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search with the following attributes.

1. `answers:0` - this restricts it to no answers at all.
2. `[tagname]` - Replace "tagname" with the tags you want to filter by. If you want to search for questions that have multiple tags, contain each in brackets. Note that you cannot do an OR type search in combination with `answers:0`, though.
3. To top it off, just pick the `newest` sort tab. If you're on the URL, it's just `?tab=newest`.

Voila! Questions with no answers at all, most recent ask date at top, and filtered by specific tabs. [Here is an example for Stack Overflow's C# tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[c%23]%20answers%3a0)

Comment: Works for me.  Would still be great if I didn't have to type anything to get those results but it is pretty easy as is.  I wonder if maybe some of the criteria I mentioned above (or any other metric) could enable the "UI Easter Egg" to make this sorting a little easier on specific SE sites.  Thank you for the help.